# Empty Spinner with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to populate a spinner with a SimpleCursorAdapter. But the spinner is totally empty; it just doesn't show items. I do not get error messages.

I've been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong for hours. I really hope you can help me.

This is the onCreate function in my activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.insert);

    spinner     = (Spinner)     findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    fillSpinner();
}
```

This is the function that should populate the spinner:

```
private void fillSpinner() {
        Db = new DbAdapter(this);
        Db.open();
        final Cursor cursor = Db.getCats(true,true);

        Log.d("fillSpinner","cursor.getCount: "+cursor.getCount()+" / cursor.getColumnCount: "+cursor.getColumnCount());//returns 8 and 4

        String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, from, to);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //...   

        cursor.close();
        Db.close();
    }
```

And this is my getCats() function in my DbAdapter class:

```
public Cursor getCats(boolean times, boolean adapter) {

        String id = KEY_ID;
        if(adapter){
            id = KEY_ID +" "+_ID;
        }

        String columns = id+", "+KEY_NAME;
        if(times){
            columns+=", "+KEY_START+", "+KEY_END;
        }
        return Db.rawQuery("SELECT "+columns+" FROM "+CATS_TABLE+" ORDER BY "+KEY_ID+" ASC", null);
    }
```

And my constants:

```
private static final String CATS_TABLE  = "cats";

public static final String KEY_ID       = "id";
public static final String KEY_NAME     = "name";
public static final String KEY_START    = "start";
public static final String KEY_END      = "end";

public static final String _ID          = "_id";
```

Thanks in advance!

Yellos

Comment: can you attach the log? is the counter filled? ...

Comment: cursor.getCount() returns 8 and cursor.getColumnCount() returns 4. There are no errors in the log.

Comment: not expert on Cursors but wouldn't this help `cursor.moveToPosition(-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close the cursor.

The cursor must remain open while you use the spinner.  After you call the cursor let the system handle closing it by calling `startManagingCursor`.  It will close it when you are done w/o you having to worry about it.

```
final Cursor cursor = Db.getCats(true,true); 
this.startManagingCursor(cursor);
```